# MySQL / MariaDB get Unix Timestamp from DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How do I convert a DATETIME column into a Unix Timestamp?

I have tried the following:

```sql
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) FROM Foo
```

`date` is the DATETIME column and `Foo` the table. However, this selection will always return `NULL`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eee4399e6d7c633be2463423cd282e6e Please provide table structure, sample data and MySQL version

Comment: @Lehks . . . Without sample data, your question does not make sense.